# SelectBox with form controller and remote model

Tags: qooxdoo

We are building a larger Qooxdoo application, and we have the following problem.

We try to bind a SelectBox (qx.ui.form.SelectBox) with a remote model to a form controller (qx.ui.form.Form) with property binding.
The form controller has also a remote model.
The form and the list are connected over a list controller (qx.data.controller.List).

The problem now are race conditions between this two models.
Both models are connected to a REST interface.

Is there a solution like a virtual selectbox, or a alternative?

UPDATE:
The main problem is the default selection of the select box when editing data in the form.
The user clicks on a button and the form gets opened in a new window. The form contents will be loaded via REST. In the form there is a select box containing all countries of the world (as example) loaded via REST, and Germany should be selected as default. This default selection is only possible, if all counties are already loaded via REST. Otherwise the first element in the list is selected.

Here is some example source code, it's not working, but is a good starting point: http://tinyurl.com/oqsfkrc

Answer (score 0):

Virtual select box does not help you much because it's only virtual when it comes to rendering. So the data binding and the race conditions should be the same no matter which select box you choose.
I don't get the root of your problem so I can't give you a precise advice how to handle your race condition. Is it possible to load / set the models sequentially to break the race condition?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added a more detailed problem description & example.